# Optional param with query Spring-Boot jpa 1.5

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I want to execute query for filter list with spring boot 1.5, I have param required (username) and optional param (email), How I can assign optional for param in query ?
@Query("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.username LIKE :username AND u.email=:email")
public Page getUsers(@Param("username") String username, @Param("email") String email); 
http://localhost:8080/users?username=&email=test : work fine
http://localhost:8080/users?username= : Exception

Comment: Create two methods, and call one or the other depending on the presence of the email.

Comment: I really have many params for filter but for this question I simply for two params, How I can execute query with required and optional param ?

Comment: Use the JPA criteria API to dynamically create the query, or QueryDSL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use JPA criteria API like this:

First, create a `Specification` object:

```
private Specification<Item> createSpecification(ItemSearch itemSearch) {
    return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> criteriaBuilder.and(
            Stream.of(
                    itemSearch.getUsername() == null ? null : criteriaBuilder.like(root.get("username"), itemSearch.getUsername()),
                    itemSearch.getEmail() == null ? null : criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("email"), itemSearch.getEmail())
            ).filter(Objects::nonNull).toArray(Predicate[]::new)
    );
}
```

Extend your repository from `JpaSpecificationExecutor`:

```
public interface ItemRepository extends CrudRepository<Item, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Item> {

}
```

Select all items using the specification:

```
List<Item> items = itemRepository.findAll(createSpecification(itemSearch))
```